# PHP - Execute python script on remote IP address and get result

Tags: python, php, cmd, psexec

here is what I am trying to do:

I have a PHP application running on a web server. There is also an other virtual machine (in the same network with the appropriate permissions) where there is a python script. Now, what I want to do is from the PHP to run the python script on the remote machine and get back the result.

The following code runs correctly on the cmd on the server.

```
cd C:\pstools
psexec.exe \\192.168.0.ip cmd
cd "path of the python script on the remote machine"
python main.py
```

This works great and returns the result.

Now... how do I run this from PHP? I already tried with exec commands and I also tried with .bat file. I mean, to right the code on a batch file and execute it with the exec command through PHP.

The batch files looks like this:

```
cd /d C:\pstools
psexec.exe -h -accepteula \\192.168.0.ip cmd
cd "path of the python script on the remote machine"
python main.py
```

This finishes without an error, but doesn't seem to actually run the cmd on the remote machine. I've also tried some variations of the psexec command, like adding the path of the file on the same command, but still no luck.

Any idea on how to address this would be appreciated!
Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: `exec` does stuff on the machine where PHP runs. If you have your python script on a different machine, then you need to find a way to access that from your PHP server in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that I figured out :( That is why I moved to the idea with the batch file. But this is not producing the desired result neither!

Comment: Using psexec I managed to run the script on the second machine from the cmd on the first machine and get the result correctly. So, if I run the exact same code in a batch file, wouldn't I get the same result? If so, I can run the batch file from PHP on machine 1. At least, this was the initial idea.

Comment: _“So, if I run the exact same code in a batch file, wouldn't I get the same result?”_ - if that happens under the same user, with the same rights/permissions, as your succesful attempt on the command line - then I’d assume yes.